# StreamReader.Read text out of order

Tags: c#, streamreader, networkstream

I'm trying to send the Base64 string of a screenshot to the server via NetworkStream and it appears I'm receiving the full string, problem is it's scrambled...

I assume this has something to do with it being fragmented and put back together? What would be the appropriate way to go about this...

Client Code

```
byte[] ImageBytes = Generics.Imaging.ImageToByte(Generics.Imaging.Get_ScreenShot_In_Bitmap());
string StreamData = "REMOTEDATA|***|" + Convert.ToBase64String(ImageBytes);
SW.WriteLine(StreamData);
SW.Flush();
```

Server Code

```
char[] ByteData = new char[350208];
SR.Read(ByteData, 0, 350208);
string Data = new string(ByteData);
File.WriteAllText("C:\\RecievedText", Data);
```

Also the size of the sent message and the char array are exactly the same.\

EDIT:
**After messing around with it some more I realized the text isnt scrambled but the proper text is trailing the previous stream.. How can I ensure the stream is clear or gets the entire text**

Comment: First problem: you're calling `SR.Read` but ignoring the return value. Why? I *very* much doubt that it's really getting "scrambled" - I suspect you're misdiagnosing the issue, to be honest... but you haven't provided us enough data to go on.

Comment: Just for fun, try placing the StreamWriter into a `using` block.

Comment: @Jon All I'm doing at the moment is immediately writing the buffer to a text file to compare outputs. The writtentext is completely scrambled and out of order when compared to the original sent text

Comment: @jon you were right the text is scrambled but it's being mixed in with the previous stream.. How do I negate this?

Comment: @user2379231: You haven't told us anything about a "previous stream". It sounds like you need to give us a *lot* more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: The client code I provided is all there is to it. It executes that on a separate looped thread and sleeps for 1ms after each execution. So it's just sending a series of screenshots. The ONLY other thing that's sent besides this is the server sends "RDP" which the client reads to invoke the looped function above.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're not reading all of the previous response. You have to read in a loop until you get no data, like this:

```
char[] ByteData = new char[350208];
int totalChars = 0;
int charsRead;
while ((charsRead = SR.Read(ByteData, totalChars, ByteData.Length - totalChars) != 0)
{
    totalChars += charsRead;
}
string Data = new string(ByteData, 0, totalChars);
File.WriteAllText("C:\\RecievedText", Data);
```

The key here is that [StreamReader.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824.aspx) reads *up to* the maximum number of characters you told it to. If there aren't that many characters immediately available, it will read what's available and return those. The return value tells you how many it read. You have to keep reading until you get the number of characters you want, or until `Read` returns `0`.

Comment: No luck. There's always the amount of bytes I specified so I don't think it has to do with there not being enough. I appreciate the insight though.

Comment: @user2379231: The point is that there *isn't* always enough. Data is sent in relatively small packets from client to server. So with your code the server is going to read one packet and say, "Well, I'm done,"  before the client can send another packet. You should capture the return value from your call to `SR.Read` and output it somehow. I think you'll be surprised.

Comment: I wasn't even aware Read returned a value, after looking on msdn I see it returns the characters read. I'll play around with this a bit thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear both the server listener and client sender are looped sending continuous data. I tried outputting the Read value and its always the length of the char[]